# If a browser can shows Accept-Encoding of deflate, can it handle .NET gzipped responses?

Tags: c#, .net, http, compression, cross-browser

I'm looking at this method in this [HTTPCombiner](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/HttpCombiner):

```
private bool CanGZip(HttpRequest request)
{
    string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding) &&
         (acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip") || acceptEncoding.Contains("deflate")))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

If this returns true then the response is compressed using a `GZipStream`. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two different algorithms :

- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3
- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5

Some code here :

- http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2008/07/06/finding-preferred-accept-encoding-header-in-csharp.aspx

So, according to the protocol, it is not right, as if the browser says "give me the content using deflate", you shouldn't send it back gzipped.

Answer (score 3):

GZip (which is based on Deflate) and Deflate are two different algorithms, so a request for "deflate" should definitely not return gzipped content.

However, this should be easy to fix, by simply using a `GZipStream` if the accept header contains "gzip" and a `DeflateStream` for "deflate".

Both are included in `System.IO.Compression`, so it's not like you'd have to code your own deflate algorithm or use a third party implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Typically most of the browsers understand GZip and Deflate. They tell the server by specifying it in the request header as `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate`. The HTTPCombiner gives preference to GZip. If both the types are present then GZip is given the preference. HttpCombiner will send the content only if the browser requests for Defalte only.